# I have multiple downvotes on this question. Is there any obvious reason that I don't see

Tags: discussion

This is the question. To me it seems to fulfil all the stack overflow rules but maybe I'm missing something and I'd really like to avoid doing whatever it was again.

[How can I reliably reset the Woocommerce user selected shipping method in the cart during testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105772/how-can-i-reliably-reset-the-woocommerce-user-selected-shipping-method-in-the-ca)

Comment: I'm guessing unclear.  I looked over it for a bit and didn't see an answerable question.  Then I glanced at the answer and saw your comment that started out "That's not really the question I'm asking but thanks" (that you accepted and awarded a bounty to(?)). Note that a bounty will attract more eyeballs and more eyes will vote. And your edit about not asking for a programmatic way to do it... its all quite confused.

Comment: Two reasons: It's not a programming question ("I'm looking for an administrative way to do this, not a programming one") and before that edit, it was unclear what you were asking (hence the close votes).

Comment: wow so asking how a question gets downvoted gets me 2 immediate downvotes and the question closed ... I am amazed. This is not civic. I give up. The help section doesn't preculde the question as I read it but who really cares.

Comment: Welcome to the meta effect. You draw attention to something, and you may find there were people who agreed with the original assessment.

Comment: I suppose ... the entire thing is pretty depressing ... democracy really does as they say lead to mob rule. Anyway I have better things to do than trying to educate myself about the unknown depths of SO

Answer (score 4):

People can downvote as they see fit, and don't have to explain. The hovertext for downvoting is:

> "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

I don't know for sure, and unless a downvoter chooses to explain then we'll never know. But I would guess the root of the problem is: "I'm looking for an operational way to do this, not a programmatic one" - Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions, so your question is bordering on off topic.

Either that, or it's clarity - takes a few passes to interpret exactly what you're asking (at least, from my perspective as a 'not-php-person'). So maybe that too?

Comment: yes I considered that but I dont see it in the Help section that questions need to be specific to programming. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: The downvotes almost all came after I edited the quesiton

Comment: It doesn't, but it does list: `a specific programming problem`, or
`a software algorithm`, or
`software tools commonly used by programmers`; and is
`a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development` - presumably people who downvoted didn't think your question was one of these. (Which is entirely down to their opinion, which isn't always correct).